# Using increment to act as a column to add values into arraylist after splitting

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, split

I am using Java running on eclipse IDE .
I am trying to achieve a outcome of

```
Name: John
Money: 900
Password: john321

Name: Mark
Money: 300
Password: mark321
```

from a text file like this

```
//name|money|password

 john|900|john321
 mark|300|mark321
```

Here is what i tried:

```
public static void ReadFile() throws IOException {      
    FileReader rf = new FileReader("Data.dat");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(rf);
    String reader;
    ArrayList<String> dataInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((reader = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        dataInfo.add(reader);
    } // end of while loop
    br.close();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> money = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i =0; i<dataInfo.size();i++) {      
          String[] test = dataInfo.get(i).split("\\|"); 
          int j =0;
            for(String data : test) {
                //System.out.println(data); // this print like what i wanted from the above outcome i posted
                if(j==0){
                    name.add(data); 
                    System.out.println(name); // This works well.
                   j++;
                }
                if(j==1){
                    password.add(data); 
                     System.out.println(password); //ERROR this print the name instead          
                    j++;
                }
                if(j==2){
                    money.add(data);
                    System.out.println(money); //ERROR this print the name instead
                    j++;
                }
            }
    }//end of for-loop

    for(int k =0;k<name.size();k++)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " +name.get(k));
        System.out.println("Money: " +money.get(k));
        System.out.println("Password: " +password.get(k));
        System.out.println("\n"); 
    }
}
```

i am trying to make use of variable **j** to act as a column because further down the program i need to make use of the name,money,password for a filter search. i need the iteration on the for loop because i want to delete the whole text when users input the name of the user they wish to delete for e.g. `if(name.get(i) = john) { //delete password.get(i) , money.get(i) }` but the problem now is that the values i added into my arrayList is always the name only , where as **System.out.println(data)** prints everything.

Answer (score 2):

You need `else if` statements as currently it will firstly do

```
if j == 0 then increment j
```

then it will do

```
if j == 1 - yes it is
```

Anyway a cleaner way (IMO) is to do

```
String[] test = dataInfo.get(i).split("\\|"); 
if (test.length == 3) {
   just use test[0] test[1] and test[2]
}
else {
   // otherwise this is bad data - need to do something special
}
```

If you really insists on use a construct like `j` then why bother using a `for-each` block, why not just use a traditional `for` loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < test.length; j++)
```

**Also** why do you use three ArrayList's

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> money = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It would make more sense to have one `Object` with three fields `name`, `money` `password`

and then to have an ArrayList of these Objects

```
ArrayList<MyObject> people = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that your `if` blocks do absolutely nothing for the program flow. Every block is entered on every iteration, because the cases are not exclusive to each other.

You have to use `else` to ensure that only one block is entered per iteration.

```
for(String data : test) {
            //System.out.println(data); // this print like what i wanted from the above outcome i posted
            if(j==0){
                name.add(data); 
                System.out.println(name); // This works well.
               j++;
            }
            else if(j==1){
                password.add(data); 
                 System.out.println(password); //ERROR this print the name instead          
                j++;
            }
            else if(j==2){
                money.add(data);
                System.out.println(money); //ERROR this print the name instead
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-arrange your if blocks as below:

```
    if(j==2){
        password.add(data); 
        System.out.println(password);         
        j++;
    }
    if(j==1){
        money.add(data);
        System.out.println(money); 
        j++;
    }
    if(j==0){
        name.add(data); 
        System.out.println(name); 
       j++;
    }
```

Other wise use if-else.

Your code shows ERROR because as you go to the first if block *j==0*
it changes value of j to 1. then it enters into second if block *j==1*.
But still variable data has value of name. data will have money and password only in next iteration of `for(String data : test)`

Note: Also I think j==1 will have money and j==2 will have password according to your text file. You have given it wrong in the if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You cann use `java.util.Scanner` to read file line by  line. Split each line with `|` and add splitted values to correspondng lists:

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> money = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("filePath"));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] split = scanner.nextLine().split("\\|");
            if(split.length==3) {
                name.add(split[0]);
                money.add(split[1]);
                password.add(split[2]);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
```